# Server to client BSON compatibility

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, vuejs2, bson

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project which uses a client side framework (VueJS). It won't be a SPA but a multi-SPA solution where each controller can have its own little client app.

Everything works fine except one thing. I try to feed the client with initial data by serializing ASP.NET model into a json/bson directly in the ASP.NET view file.

It works fine when I'm using JSON format:

```
<script>
   var ServerModel = @Json.Serialize(Model);
</script>
```

This renders the whole model as plain text into the html source. Now I try to encode that by using BSON format. On the server side I'm using Newtonsoft library which provides a BSON serializer feature:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm

How can I decode the BSON string with client side javascript? I found bson npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson. But it seems like uses different encoding/decoding type and won't recognize my bson string encoded by Newtonsoft lib.

The Newtonsoft lib produces base64 string: `Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());`

While the bson npm package accepts Uint8Array: `var doc_2 = bson.deserialize(data);`

How can I encode a server side model into a BSON string which can be decoded by client side js?

Comment: BSON stands for Binary JSON so don't encode it as Base64String on serveur side and return the content type as application/bson. Encode it as base64string is no sense to me, you'll lose all the compression benefit of BSON

Comment: I try to render json data into the view so I won't send only data as application/bson response.

Comment: Embedding BSON into an HTML page isn't a good idea. Why not have the client make a XHR call to the server on document load and pull down JSON data?

Comment: I will do that for all further operations. I looking for a solution only for the first page load to avoid additional XHR call.